# JNDI: Which operation is expensive? LDAP rebind() or (unbind() and bind())

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

Assuming that I already have an entry in LDAP and I want to change some attributes of that entry, will using rebind() JNDI call be better than to use unbind() to delete that entry and bind() to create it from scratch?

Does this depend on the Directory server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be considering either. Use `DirContext.modifyAttributes().`

Comment: Thanks EJP! I'm guessing that adding an entry is an expensive operation because the directory server does some indexing to help search for that entry faster. Does it do the same for modifying attributes?

Comment: The point is that deleting and adding back the entry is slower than leaving it there and modifying it. That should be obvious. Also, the entry may have children, which makes deletion impossible.